# Finding non-collinear vertices of a convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I'm fairly new to *Mathematica* (and programming in general tbh) and need this for a math project I'm working on.

I generate large collections of (rational, 2d) points and need to find which of these points are the vertices of the convex hull.

Some googling suggested that `MeshCoordinates` would do this, but it does not exclude points on the edges of the convex hull that are collinear with the vertices. It also gives rounded decimals but that is less of an issue.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Edit to include a simplified example, the vertices of the unit square with a redundant point (`{1, .5}`):

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, .5}}
```

Both `MeshCoordinates[ConvexHullMesh[pts]]` and `ConvexHullMesh[pts]["VertexCoordinates"]` return the point `{1, .5}`, which is clearly not a vertex of the unit square.

The points I'm generating are not random, they are the result of a fairly involved set of calculations and many of them can be collinear.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the presence of extra points that you mention in `MeshCoordinates`. It actually seems to do exactly what you need. Could you show an example where you see extra points being added?

Comment: @MarcoB I added a simple example.

Comment: kaiten, how many points are in your data set typically?

Comment: @MarcoB It varies but generally a little more than 100 per dataset. (though I'm generating hundreds of such data sets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** a brute force approach to eliminate coordinates that lie in the convex hull of other coordinates:

```
ClearAll[noncollinearF]
noncollinearF[verts_]:= Function[{k}, Nor @@ (RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[#],k]&/@ 
    Subsets[Complement[verts,{k}],{2}])]

Pick[#, noncollinearF[#] /@ #]&[Rationalize @ ConvexHullMesh[pts]["VertexCoordinates"]]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}

```
Pick[#, noncollinearF[#] /@ #]&[Rationalize@ConvexHullMesh[pts2]["VertexCoordinates"]]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}

Or define a function that picks the non-collinear vertices of the convex hull of a set of 2D points:

```
ncvF = With[{v = #}, Pick[v, Function[{k}, Nor @@ (RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[#],k]&/@ 
    Subsets[Complement[v,{k}],{2}])]/@v]]&;

 ncvF[pts]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}

```
 ncvF[pts2]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}

**Previous post:**

The function `` Geometry`ConvexHull2 `` gives the desired coordinates for the simple example:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1,1/2}};

chm = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
vertices = Rationalize[chm["VertexCoordinates"]] (* or MeshCoordinates[chm] *)
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}}

```
strictvertices = Rationalize[Geometry`ConvexHull2[ pts]]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}

```
Show[chm, Graphics@Point[pts], Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ vertices}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[chm, Graphics@Point[pts], Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ strictvertices}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

... **but**, it fails to eliminate some coordinates in an other example:

```
pts2 = {{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {1, 1}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3/2, 1/2}}

Show[ConvexHullMesh[pts2], Graphics @ Point[pts2], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ Geometry`ConvexHull2[ pts2]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I thought your code solved my problem but after a little testing it has the same flaw as MeshCoordinates. I updated my post with a simple example.

Comment: @kaiten, just noticed the update to your post. I don't think it is an issue because the point `{1, 1/2}` **is** a member of the the convex hull.

Comment: Yes, but it is not a vertex (should I call them corners?). The convex hull is a polygon, and I'm interested in the vertices of that polygon. An equivalent way to look at it would be a minimal set of points to generate the same convex hull.

Comment: @kaiten, i see your point. That seems to be a difficult problem. `ConvexHullMesh` does not eliminate collinear vertices; check for example `pts2={{0,0},{1/2,0},{1/2,1/2},{1,1},{3/2,1},{1,0},{2,1},{3/2,1/2}}`.  (Btw,  i meant `{1, 1/2}` **is**  a _vertex_ of the convex hull.)

Comment: @kaiten, please see the updated post.

Comment: @kglr (+1) Out of curiosity, how did you come across `ConvexHull2`? Do you happen to know if it's a different convex hull algorithm from `ConvexHullMesh`?

Comment: @MarcoB, just found this function using ``??*`*ConvexHull*``. Maybe the code can be obtained using version-10 `PrintDefinitions` (which I haven't tried yet)

Comment: @kglr I hoped so too, but unfortunately the code is not available; `PrintDefinitions` just reports "kernel function".

Comment: @kglr Thats really interesting. While not quite perfect, it seems to work pretty well. I'm going to mark this as a solution, but I'm still interested if you find out anything more.

Comment: @kaiten, i suggest you wait for a while before accepting an answer. I expect more/better anwers will be forthcoming.