# How to determine the longest edge in a graph?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics

I have a list of 2D points such as in the image.

```
coord = {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {20, 0}, {30, 0}, {25, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 
5}};
```

[image]

I would like to determine the longest "edge" length in a way that if 2 segments are in same line, they would be considered as part of 1 edge. For example, segments 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 are continuous and in the same line, so we consider it as 1 edge connecting Vertex 1 and Vertex 4. In this example, the longest edge length would be the distance from vertex 1 to vertex 4. How can I determine the longest edge length in Mathematica?

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** The function in the original answer does not work for arbitrary polygons. The following seems to work

```
ClearAll[nonCollinearHull]
nonCollinearHull = Module[{coords = #, 
 angles = ArcTan @@@ (Subtract @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1 , {1, 1}]),
 rotation, lengths},
rotation = LengthWhile[Reverse[angles], # == angles[[1]] &];
lengths = Length /@ Split[RotateRight[angles, rotation]];
TakeList[RotateRight[coords, rotation], lengths][[All, 1]]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
coord = {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {20, 0}, {30, 0}, {25, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 5}};
lines = Line /@ Partition[nonCollinearHull[coord], 2, 1];
longest = Last@SortBy[lines, N@ArcLength[#] &];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], Polygon@coord, Blue, 
  PointSize[Large], Point@coord, Opacity[.5, Green], 
  AbsolutePointSize[15], Point[nonCollinearHull[coord]], 
  Thickness[.03], CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], Red, longest}]
```

[image]

Using

```
SeedRandom[123]
coord2 = DeleteDuplicates[#[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]] & @
   DeleteDuplicates@RandomInteger[10, {50, 2}];
```

we get

[image]

And with

```
SeedRandom[123]
coord3 = DeleteDuplicates[#[[FindShortestTour[#][[2]]]] &@ 
   DeleteDuplicates@RandomInteger[20, {200, 2}]];
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use  `MaximalBy` to define `longest`:

```
SeedRandom[777777]
coord = MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, 50]]];
lines = Line /@ Partition[nonCollinearHull[coord], 2, 1];
longest = MaximalBy[lines, N@ArcLength[#] &];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], Line@coord, Blue, 
  PointSize[Large], Point@coord, Opacity[.5, Green], 
  AbsolutePointSize[15], Point[nonCollinearHull[coord]], 
  Thickness[.03], CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], Red, longest}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Using the function `noncollinearF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137529/125):

```
ClearAll[noncollinearF]
noncollinearF[verts_] := Function[{k}, Nor @@ (RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[#], k] & /@ 
  Subsets[Complement[verts, {k}], {2}])]

lines = Line /@ Partition[Pick[#, noncollinearF[#] /@ #], 2, 1, {1, 1}]& @ coord;
longest = Last@SortBy[lines, N@ArcLength[#] &]; 
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[], Polygon@coord, 
  Blue, PointSize[Large], Point@coord, 
  Thickness[.03], CapForm["Round"], Opacity[.5], Red, longest}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why `ConvexHullMesh` and not just `Line`?

Comment: It breaks if a coordinate list starts in the middle of the longest edge. Try `RotateLeft[coord, 2]` for the original example.

Comment: @swish, thank you. Updated with an alternative that does not have the issue.